# Parsing XML and printing attributes of one child that fits a given criteria

Tags: xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing

I have an XML response. I need to extract the `uri` attribute where `local=1` in `Connection` under the `Device` labeled `product=Plex Media Server`, or to put it succinctly, I need `this.is.what.i.want`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MediaContainer size="5">
  <Device name="Cast" product="Plex Media Server" productVersion="1.14.1.5490-33830be0b" platform="Android" platformVersion="8.0.0" device="SHIELD Android TV" clientIdentifier="" createdAt="" lastSeenAt="" provides="" owned="1" accessToken="" publicAddress="" httpsRequired="1" synced="0" relay="1" dnsRebindingProtection="0" publicAddressMatches="1" presence="1">
    <Connection protocol="https" address="12.34.56.78" port="xxx" uri="this.is.what.i.want" local="1"/>
    <Connection protocol="https" address="91.01.11.21" port="xxx" uri="https://111-111-111-111.863fffffffffffffflf.plex.direct:xxx" local="0"/>
  </Device>
  <Device name="TV" product="Plex for Samsung" productVersion="2.012" platform="Samsung" platformVersion="5.1" device="Samsung TV" clientIdentifier="xxx" createdAt="" lastSeenAt="" provides="client,player,pubsub-player" owned="1" publicAddress="" publicAddressMatches="0" presence="0" accessToken="">
    <Connection protocol="https" address="xx.xx.xx.xx" port="xx" uri="https://222-222-222-222.863ffffffffffffffff.plex.direct:xxx" local="1"/>
    <Connection protocol="https" address="xx.xx.xx.xx" port="xx" uri="https://333-444-555-666.863ffffffffffffffff.plex.direct:xxx" local="0"/>
  </Device>
</MediaContainer>
```

I'm a super newb. I can get the last uri to print

```
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for Connection in root.iterfind('Device/Connection'):
    uri = Connection.get('uri')

print(uri)
```

Result:

```
https://333-444-555-666.863ffffffffffffffff.plex.direct:xxx
```

However when I try to add some qualifiers my code falls apart:

```
tofind = set(['Device/@product'])

for Device in root.findall('Device'):
    for product in tofind:
        node = Device.find('Plex Media Server')
        if node is not None:
            print ('Found uri')
        else:
            print ('Unable to find uri')

print(Device.attrib)
```

Result:

```
Unable to find uri
Unable to find uri
{'name': 'TV', 'product': 'Plex for Samsung', 'productVersion': '2.012', 'platform': 'Samsung', 'platformVersion': '5.1', 'device': 'Samsung TV', 'clientIdentifier': 'xxx', 'createdAt': '', 'lastSeenAt': '', 'provides': 'client,player,pubsub-player', 'owned': '1', 'publicAddress': '', 'publicAddressMatches': '0', 'presence': '0', 'accessToken': ''}
```

For some reason the code always prints the last device attributes and not the first.

Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: Hi! Could You share your logs/traces?

Comment: Just did, thanks for the response!

Comment: it would be great if you share your solution.